# Do I get paid to kill myself in Eridium Blight?

Tags: borderlands-2

In a quest in Eridium Blight, Handsome Jack asks me to jump off a cliff and be his bi*ch and he will reward me handsomely. From past experiences he almost never keeps his word, but still I will like to know if the reward is worth the thousands I'm gonna spent to regenerate myself.

Comment: Seriously Arqade, you gotta fix your terrible question title issue...

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The rewards if you kill yourself are:

- $0
- 12 Eridium
- 3274 EXP

If you do not kill yourself, you will receive:

- 9832 EXP

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer.. well at least this time Jack does keep his word! :D

Comment: Do I also get my zero dollars if I do not kill myself? I don't want to miss on my zero ;)